# Which compiler evaluate left most parameter first

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, operator-precedence

I know the order that function parameters are evaluated is **unspecified** in C++, see below,

// The simple obvious one.

```
callFunc(getA(),getB());
```

Can be **equivalent** to this:

```
int a = getA();
int b = getB();
callFunc(a,b);
Or this:

int b = getB();
int a = getA();
callFunc(a,b);
```

This is perfect fine & I think most ppl know this.

But I have tried VC10, gcc 4.72 and they all evaluate b first (from right to left), meaning b got pushed into stack frame first then a.

I am just wondering which c++ compiler should I try to make the code above to evalute a first ?
So a got pushed to stack before b.

Thanks

Comment: What's the point if it's unspecified anyway?

Comment: if getA() and/or getB() contains side-effects, the order could affect the result...

Comment: note this is only for fun & NOT recommending writing your code depend on this famous unspecified behavior.

Comment: You could write your own compiler, *that* is fun.

Comment: so many ppl comments none is constructive...

Comment: Note that the issue is broader than just function arguments. The order of evaluation of *any* expression is undefined. For example, in `a + b` it's not defined wether `a` is evaluated before `b`.

Comment: Also, you might want to write an example program that detects evaluation order and prints it out. Otherwise, people won't bother trying to find out what their compiler does. If, on the other hand, all they have to do is just compile the program, run it and tell you the result, you might get an actual answer.

Comment: @NikosC. It certainly isn't _any expression_: Consider things like `&&` and `||`. `a + b` basically is the function `+` with parameters `a` and `b`.

Comment: @stefan I should have said "expression without short-circtuit semantics".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter evaluation order substantially depends from the calling convention used for calling the given function - if parameters are pushed on the stack RTL it's usually more convenient to elaborate the rightmost parameters first.

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions) table, on x86 the only calling convention available on IA32 with LTR parameter order on the stack is `fastcall` on Borland, that however passes the first three integer/pointer parameters in registers. So you should write a function that takes more than three integers, mark it as `fastcall` and compile it with a Borland compiler; in that case *probably* the other parameters besides the first three should be evaluated in LTR order.

Going on other platforms probably you'll find other calling conventions with LTR parameter passing (and so probably LTR parameters evaluation).

Notice that the parameter passing order <=> parameter evaluation order are logically bound, but if for some reason the compiler finds that it's better to evaluate some parameter before the others there's nothing in the standard preventing it to do so.

Comment: Thanks. Anyone have got a Borland compile care to give this one a go?

Comment: @Nikos: that's not so simple; that program, for example, would give random results with every calling convention that uses registers to pass some of the arguments, like the case of the `fastcall` calling convention I mentioned.

Comment: Don't the functions have to be called before their return values are pushed to registers?

Comment: @NikosC. sure, but it doesn't have to call the functions in the same order they're pushed on the stack.  Heck, it doesn't even have to call the functions in the same order each time you call the same function in the same program in a loop!